# OpenMP 2 For Loops without collapse()

Tags: c, loops, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to parallel those two inner Loops with OpenMP but I don't really know how to solve the problem. It should get all primes to number `n`.

```
int sqrt_n = sqrt(n);
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, chunksize) num_threads(16)
  for (int i = 2; i < sqrt_n; i++) {
      if(array[i] != 0){
          #pragma omp atomic write
          //printf("%d ", i);
      }
      for (int j=i*i;j<n;i++){
          #pragma omp atomic write
          array[j] = 1;
      }
  }
  #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, chunksize) num_threads(16)
  for(int i = sqrt_n+1; i < n; i++){
      if(!array[i]){
          #pragma omp atomic write
          //printf("%d ", i);
      }
  }
```